# Dúvida sobre o topo de uma pilha na linguagem Java

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados

Eu sou iniciante na área de programação e estava estudando um pouco de estruturas de dados na linguagem Java. Quando comecei a estudar sobre a estrutura "pilha", tive a seguinte dúvida: Digamos que eu tenha um vetor com cinco espaços (índices que vão de 0-4), porém, apenas quatro espaços (índices que vão de 0-3) estão preenchidos, dessa forma, o "topo da pilha" é o valor "null", que está no índice "4" (que está vazio), ou é o valor "3", que não é o último índice da pilha que compõe esse vetor, porém é o último espaço do vetor que possui um valor diferente de null?

Ilustrando: vetor1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, null] - O topo da pilha é o indice "3" ou o índice "4"?

Comment: O Java oferece a classe [Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) que estende a classe Vector adicionando operações de tratamento de pilha. Também existe a classe [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) que representa uma lista duplamente encadeada que oferece métodos de edição nos dois extremos da lista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estando você implementando o conceito de pilha em um vetor, o topo da pilha será o índice 3 caso você esteja sempre inserido do menor índice para o maior.

Lembre-se que o conceito de pilha está ligado principalmente à ordem de inserção e remoção.

LIFO (Last in First out - Último a entrar Primeiro a sair). Se vocÊ for excluir um elemento dessa lista você deverá excluir o que está no índice 3 e se for inserir você deverá inserir no índice 4.

Normalmente esse conceito é implementado em uma estrutura dinâmica (Sem um limite de elementos como é o caso dos arrays)

recomendo a leitura do artigo abaixo:

https://www.devmedia.com.br/pilhas-fundamentos-e-implementacao-da-estrutura-em-java/28241